# Bash script pattern matching

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting

I need a to find patterns that are 6 digits and the first 3 digits are specific digits, but the remaining 3 digits will be any digit.
For example, 6 digit strings starting with 123 followed by any 3 digits.

```
var1="abc,123111,"
var2="abcdefg,123222,"
var3="xyzabc,987111,"

if [[ $var1 == *",123ddd,"* ]] ; then echo "Pattern matched"; fi
```

Where ddd are any digits.  var1 and var2 would match the pattern but var 3 would not.  I can't seem to get it just right.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Use a character class: `[0-9]` matches `0`, `9`, and every character between them in the character set, which - at least in Unicode (e.g. UTF-8) and subset character sets (e.g. US-ASCII, Latin-1) -  are the digits `1` through `8`. So it matches any one of the 10 Latin digits.

```
if [[ $var1 == *,123[0-9][0-9][0-9],* ]] ; then echo "Pattern matched"; fi
```

Using `=~` instead of `==` changes the pattern type from shell standard "glob" patterns to regular expressions ("regexes" for short). You can make an equivalent regex a little shorter:

```
if [[ $var1 =~ ,123[0-9]{3}, ]] ; then echo "Pattern matched"; fi
```

The first shortening comes from the fact that `[[ =~ ]]` only requires the regex to match any part of the string, not the whole thing. Therefore you don't need the equivalent of the leading and trailing `*`s that you find in the glob pattern.

The second length reduction is due to the `{n}` syntax, which lets you specify a number of repetitions of the previous pattern without actually repeating the pattern itself in the regex. (You can also match any of a range of repetition counts by specifying a minimum and maximum: `[0-9]{2,4}` will match either two, three, or four digits in a row.)

It's worth noting that you could also use a named character class to match digits. Depending on your locale, `[[:digit:]]` may be exactly equivalent to `[0-9]`, or it may include characters from other scripts with the Unicode "Number, Decimal Digit" property.

```
if [[ $var1 =~ ,123[[:digit:]]{3}, ]] ; then echo "Pattern matched"; fi
```

Comment: Nicely done. Quibble: `[0-9]` matches the characters in the range `0` through `9` _as defined by the (effective) `LC_CTYPE`  value_ (see `locale`). In the now-ubiquitous UTF-8-based locales, this coincides with the ASCII/Latin-1 characters `0` through `9`, because these encodings are true _subsets_ of Unicode. By contrast `[[:digits:]]` matches not just `0` through `9`, but also  _additional_ characters in UTF-8, based on what the Unicode standard considers a digit.

Answer (score 2):

Bash *glob pattern matching* `[0-9]` can be used to match digit:

```
if [[ $var1 == *,123[0-9][0-9][0-9],* ]] ; then echo "Pattern matched"; fi
```

Alternatively, you can use *regex pattern matching* with `=~`:

```
if [[ $var1 =~ .*,123[0-9]{3},.* ]] ; then echo "Pattern matched"; fi
```