# Regular expression matching and finding file of particular type using shell script

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I have a situation where I am iterating folder and subfolders using shell script. Once I reached at sub-directory whose name will be like **1.5.8/10.50.80.500**(**basically containing numbers and periods**) I am trying to find two different kinds of file having certain extension *.jar and *.pom. But the problem is all the folders whose names are basically alphabets are also full-filling the condition related to the file name. Appreciate your help.

```
    for FILE in $(find . -type d) ;
    do
    if test -d $FILE ; 
    then 
        if [[ $FILE == */[[[1-9]\.[1-9]\.[1-9]] || [[1-9]*\.[1-9]*\.[1-9]*]] ]] ; 
        then 
             echo "**********************************************************"
             echo $FILE
             #echo "**********************************************************"

             pom_file=find . -name "*.pom"
             jar_file=find . -name "*.jar"

        fi
     fi
 done;
```

Currently the code is printing everything below is the output

```
 ./javax
**********************************************************
./javax/biz
**********************************************************
./javax/biz/pivotal
**********************************************************
./javax/biz/pivotal/active
**********************************************************
./javax/biz/pivotal/active/4.3.4
**********************************************************
```

But ideally the last line of the output should only be printed as that should match the pattern.

Comment: You are doing a pattern match. But look at the pattern it seems wrong. Where are you enforcing to really match numbers? In particular `*` means glob in this context.

Comment: Also, in line one you use `find` to find files which are directories, then you do another and check to see if the file is a directory, why? I believe your whole script can be simplified to one `find` expression.

Comment: @stephanmg Sorry i am  new to this but the place I am using find is actually I am trying to find the file of particular type having extension like *.pom and *.jar

Comment: Maybe you will enjoy this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44688460/bash-script-pattern-matching

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest going from bash pattern matching to regex matching via changing `==` to `=~` as follows (Is it intentional that you want to exclude the 0 digit?):

```
if [[ "$FILE" =~ [1-9]+\.[1-9]\.+[1-9]+$ ]]; then
   echo "File matches"
fi
```

Probably a more reasonable approach would be to use `find` and use the `-iregex` option. In this way this can be compressed entirely into one statement.

Comment: What happens if the if the folder name will be like 100.3.500.120 . I have added one more period and number

Comment: It will still match. We are checking that at the very end of the directory string there are at least 3 numbers separated by a period.

Answer (score 2):

Please try the following:

```
find . -regextype posix-egrep -regex '.*/([[:digit:]]+\.)*[[:digit:]]+/[^/]+\.(jar|pom)'
```

It matches a file which satisfies:

- has an extension `.jar` or `.pom`
- the parent directory name is composed of numbers and optional dots such as `1`, `1.20`, `1.20.3` etc.

[Update]
If you want to print just the directory names which contain the specified files, you can say instead:

```
find . -regextype posix-egrep -regex '.*/([[:digit:]]+\.)*[[:digit:]]+/[^/]+\.(jar|pom)' -print0 | xargs -0 -L 1 dirname
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Upvoted because of its simplicity and cleverness, but be aware that this prints the `jar/pom` files and  not the directories containing them like asked.

Comment: @Camusensei Thank you for the suggestion. I've updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Going the other way around, you could find all `pom/jar` files and only print the directories you want:

```
find . -name '*.pom' -or -name '*.jar' -printf '%P\n' |
  sed -En '\_/[0-9.]+/[^/]+.(jar|pom)$_ s_/[^/]+$__ p' |
  sort -u
```

Here, `find` lists the `pom/jar` files, `sed` filters only the directories which match characters among `[0-9.]` and prints them, and `sort -u` removes duplicates.

Note: If you care about the order in which `find` outputs the directories, you can sort without losing the original order with `awk '!seen[$0]++'`

EDIT: More inforrmation about sed, I'm using the code `match substitute print` which works as follows:

- print is only done when a substitution occured
- substitution is only done if it the input matches and only if the previous `match` part matches
- I'm using `_` as a delimiter instead of `/` because I use `/` in the patterns

Comment: Can you combine the `-name` expressions to alternation maybe via `-iregex`?

Comment: Yes but I'm not sure if it's more readable: `find . -regex '.*\.\(pom\|jar\)' -printf '%P\n'` or `find . -regextype posix-egrep -regex '.*\.(pom|jar)' -printf '%P\n'`